# SSRS 2008 draw lines on report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have 2 sets of coordinates in a table. The first set is XFrom and YFrom and the other set is XTo and YTo. If you draw a line between these two coordinates then you get an arrow.

I would like to draw these arrows in a report, for as many rows as the table has.

XFrom        YFrom     XTo      YTo

1            1         3        3

2            2         4        4

1            2         5        6

Each row represents an arrow

I can't seems to find a way.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this in SSRS?

Comment: I am creating a report that I want to contain this information. Is there another way and then I add the image in ssrs?

Comment: You can add different images of arrows depending on values you get from the data base but it looks like you would have too many permutations for it to be that useful

Comment: How many types of arrows do you want?

Comment: What do you mean by types? The arrows are not set beforehand. Each arrow might be unique as to where it begins and where it ends and this gives many shapes and directions. It will show the passes in a soccer game...

Comment: Okay in that case I would not use SSRS. You can do stuff like this pretty easily in HTML. Or if you didn't want to use web you could write a program to do it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but i there is a way to do this is SSRS then it will fit perfectly in my report I have created in SSRS. or if there is a way to produce this elsewhere and add it to the report later?

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop a chart control from the toolbox.
As soon as you do that , you get a pop-up, displaying various image shapes for the chart control & try to choose your option.

Comment: Will I be able to connect 2 sets of coordinates? How?